# Ajax function returns success but controller function is not executing

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'm trying to get the laravel-favorite system (https://github.com/ChristianKuri/laravel-favorite) to work. I've installed it like its told by the readme.

When I click on the like button it returns success but the function seems not to get executed.

I've tried the ajax to be like this:

```
$('.btn-heart').on('click', function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://localhost/view/<?php echo $post->post_id; ?>',
    data: {post_id: '<?php echo $post->post_id; ?>'},
    success: function(data){
      alert('working')
    },
error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
    }  
  });
})
```

or like this

```
$('.btn-heart').on('click', function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://localhost/view/',
    data: {post_id: '<?php echo $post->post_id; ?>'},
    success: function(data){
      alert('working')
    },
error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
    }  
  });
})
```

I have to be clear that post_id is my unique post_id from my posts table.

My view.blade.php:

```
<div class="card-body no-padding">
                <div class="card-image-wrapper">
                    <div class="img-card-img">
                        <img src="{{ $post->post_url }}" class="card-image"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="overlay-img"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-padding-user">
                    <div class="float-left">
                        <button class="btn btn-default btn-heart"><i class="far fa-heart icon-middle icon-thre"></i><i class="fa fa-heart icon-middle icon-non"></i> <span class="align-middle ml-2">0 Likes</span></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

My web.php:

```
Route::get('/view/{post_id}',"PostController@like");
```

My PostController:

```
public function like($post_id)
    {
        $post = Post::where('post_id', $post_id)->first();
        $user = Auth::user(); 
        $user->toggleFavorite($post); 
        return response()->json(['status' => 1]);
    }
```

My Usermodel:

```
use Notifiable;
    use Favoriteability;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'avatar', 'full_name'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function posts() {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class, 'creator','name');
    }
```

My Post model:

```
use Favoriteable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'creator', 'post_url', 'game', 'likes', 'created_at'
    ];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

Somehow the function isnt working at all, nothing gets inserted to the favorite table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've managed to get it to work.

Instead of using a GET Method you need to use POST method and include a CSRF token

```
$('.button-like').on('click', function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: '/view/<?php echo $post->post_id; ?>',
    data: {postid: '<?php echo $post->post_id; ?>', _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'}
  });
})
```